# mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource

Tags: php, mysql

this is my php code for getting number of rows from database.but i m getting error like mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource. how to remove that error. plz help me
thanks in advance.

```
 include("db.php");
                    if(isset($_GET['page']))
                    {
                        $page=$_GET['page'];
                        $page=mysql_real_escape_string($page);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $page=1;
                    }
                    $per_page = 5;
                  $res =mysql_query("select * from depart");
                  $count = mysql_num_rows($res);
                  $pages = ceil($count/$per_page);
```

Comment: where is the php code?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have your options stored in $options, I would do something like this.

```
<select>
    <?php foreach($options as $option): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $option->id; ?>">
            <?php echo $option->name; ?>
        </option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Or, the slightly prettier:

```
<select>  
    <?php  
        foreach($options as $option) {  
            echo "<option value='$option->id'>$option->name</option>  
        }  
    ?>  
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

echo ""; //echo "select"; select is not display in echo part

```
  foreach($options as $key=>$value) {
    echo "<option value='".$value['id']."'>".$value['name']."</option>";
  }
```

echo "";

try this